# SQL - List items in 1 table, only if x is true in another

Tags: mysql, sql

So I need to make a query where 4 columns are listed from a table named 'tutorial'. However, items in these columns can only be listed if there is more than one student in them.

I currently have the columns I need from the TUTORIAL table, but I am not sure how to only list tutorials with more than one student. Any help is appreciated.

Table Setups:

```
STUDENT
    (REGNUM NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     FAMILY_NAME VARCHAR(30),
     FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(30),
     YOB SMALLINT
) ;

ROOM
  (LOCATION VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   CAPACITY DECIMAL(3)
) ;

TOPIC
    (TOPIC_NUMBER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     TOPIC_NAME VARCHAR(40)
) ;

ENROLMENT
(
     REGNUM NUMERIC(10),
     TOPIC_NUMBER VARCHAR(10),
     FOREIGN KEY (REGNUM) REFERENCES
               STUDENT(REGNUM),
     FOREIGN KEY (TOPIC_NUMBER) REFERENCES
               TOPIC(TOPIC_NUMBER),
     PRIMARY KEY (REGNUM,TOPIC_NUMBER)
) ;

TUTORIAL
    (TUTEID DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     TOPIC_NUMBER VARCHAR(10),
     LOCATION VARCHAR(8),
     TUTEDAY VARCHAR(10),
     TUTETIME VARCHAR(8),
     FOREIGN KEY(TOPIC_NUMBER) REFERENCES TOPIC(TOPIC_NUMBER),
     FOREIGN KEY(LOCATION) REFERENCES ROOM(LOCATION)
) ;

TUTORIALBOOKING
    (REGNUM NUMERIC(10),
     TUTEID DECIMAL(10),
     FOREIGN KEY(REGNUM) REFERENCES STUDENT(REGNUM),
     FOREIGN KEY(TUTEID) REFERENCES TUTORIAL(TUTEID),
     PRIMARY KEY(REGNUM,TUTEID)
);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: Provide the relevant data inside your question and not as a link to other websites (when possible).

Comment: Yup, it has been fixed.

Comment: Sweet. Now all you have left to do is edit into your question your current sql statement

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question was, "I have this data but I'm not sure how to think about it and, therefore, really don't know how to start."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM TUTORIAL WHERE TUTEID in (SELECT TUTEID FROM TUTORIALBOOKING HAVING COUNT(TUTEID)>1)
```

That may not be quite right.  I don't have a test DB to plug it into at the moment.